# Would GRE Help When Applying To Doctorate Programs Without Prior Research Experience?

Tags: phd, research-undergraduate, gre

I graduated in 2022 from a 4-year BS(CS) program. During university, I was mostly occupied with Software Engineering, gaining experience, developing projects, and what not. However, I missed out on building a research profile and publishing a paper. I realized this as I was graduating, and that if I had a published paper, it would help me immensely with my application process.

After graduation, my career orientation has been toward applying for a Ph.D. program in the US. I realized I lack research experience. However, I have come to believe that attaining impressive GRE scores could help me in my attempt to land a good scholarship at a prestigious university. I graduated with 3.66 CGPA, with 3.5+ SGPA across 6 semesters. I've performed well, and my teachers are willing to write strong letters of recommendation for me. Is my assumption true that GRE will still be a support, or is that a wavering concern in today's admission process? I'm just very, very, very anxious when comparing myself to some of my peers who DO have research experience. The university I graduated from did not have a large emphasis on research, which is why I just never gained awareness until I was about to graduate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the GRE is required, then supply it. Otherwise I'd suggest that you don't. In the US, the application process already considers a broad range of information, with letters especially important. The GRE is becoming much less important in some programs for a variety of reasons and it, alone, doesn't predict research success. Those letters, however, from people who know you are expected to honestly predict your success.

If you've taken the exam and have an outstanding score then there is no harm in submitting it, but if it isn't asked for it isn't likely to count for much.

You aren't normally expected to already have research experience in a CS undergraduate program when applying for a doctoral program. That, in itself won't be an issue. The program is designed to give you that experience. The program normally starts with advanced coursework leading to comprehensive exams.

---

See the answer for the US to this canonical question for more:
[How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368)

Comment: Right, thanks! I was seeking validation about the prior research experience, though. Thank you for clearing that up.